# Excel Sumproduct OR function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use OR function inisde SUMPRODUCT.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(OR(A:A="FROG",A:A="PAN",B:B)
```

and obviously it didn't work.

I am trying to add both "Frog" and "Pan" prices.

```
A         B
Frog     15
Cow      25
Pan      01
Frog     235
Tiger    99
Sheep    178
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution:

[image]

The formula is:

`=SUMMENPRODUKT((A1:A6="s")+(A1:A6="t");B1:B6)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A,{"frog","pan"},B:B))
```

[image]